# How to encode in XML on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am generating XML as follows:

```
SET @xml = (
        SELECT 
                PersonalMessage AS [Personal_Message]
        FROM #TemporaryDB
        FOR XML PATH ('Order'), ROOT ('Orders'), ELEMENTS
        );
```

Next I add encoding info:

```
SELECT N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + Convert(nvarchar(max), @XML)
```

And when I save my XML with `bcp` I get something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders><Order>
<Personal_Message>Liebe X1 und X2,
"Wir wuenschten wir koennten heute mit euch zusammen sitzen. Das holen wir bald wieder nach."
Eure &amp; Ina </Personal_Message></Order></Orders>
```

But I want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders><Order>
<Personal_Message>Liebe X1 und X2,&#13;&#13; &quot;Wir wuenschten wir koennten heute mit euch zusammen sitzen. Das holen wir bald wieder nach.&quot; &#13;&#13;Eure &amp; Ina </Personal_Message></Order></Orders>
```

So I want to change `C/R` to `&#13;` and for example `"` to `&quot;`.

Please, advise me. How can I do this?

Comment: can you include your `bcp` command here? what is the format in your `bcp`?

Comment: bcp TABLENAME out path/fle.xml  -S server -T -c

Comment: do you insert this xml back into a table and then use a bcp on that table?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And still I have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to replace it

```
SET @xml = (
        SELECT 
                Replace(Replace(Replace(PersonalMessage,char(13),'&#13;'),char(10),''),'"','&quot;') AS [Personal_Message]
        FROM #TemporaryDB
        FOR XML PATH ('Order'), ROOT ('Orders'), ELEMENTS
        );
```